# Update an item column in a table related to a field in an other table (2 tables case) android room database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-mvvm

Simple grocery app on Android. Everything is local using Room DataBase, using MVVM model and Kotlin. I have a `DataBase`, a `Repository` and a `ViewModel`. I am practicing with this app and I am not comfortable with `DataBase` presently.

I have two tables:

- `ShoppingItems` (Items I want)
- `ReferenceItems` (Items I usually buy and know the price)

In the `ReferenceItems` table I have 3 columns:

- Id
- Name (unique)
- Unit Price

In the `ShoppingItems` table I have the following columns:

- Id (PrimaryKey)
- Name
- Amount
- Reference Id (Foreign Key) (if the id is in the Reference table else I got an Id from a default reference item I pre populated in the table)
- Unit Price ( = corresponding reference item Unit Price)

Now, everything works perfectly using `LiveData<>` to read information such as quantity or total price.

**My question is: Can I use only the `ReferenceItems` Id in the `ShoppingItems` table to get the Unit Price.**

In fact, the user will be able to edit the unit price in the `ReferenceItems` table if needed. I would like the app to update only ONE field, in `ReferenceItems` table. In the actual situation I will have to update the price in `ReferenceItems` table AND `ShoppingItems` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use only the ReferenceItems Id in the ShoppingItems table to get the Unit Price

Yes, you can.

**Scenario 1 (without auxiliary class)**.

Change you query in dao to something like this:

```
@Query("select shoppingItems.*, referenceItems.unitPrice from shoppingItems left join referenceItems on shoppingItems.referenceId=referenceItems.id")
LiveData<List<ShoppingItems>> getShoppingItems()
```

But to achieve that - you have to keep you "unitPrice" field in your "shoppingItems" class (of course, you can leave it empty while inserting data). You can play with @Ignore annotation trying not persist this field the the db, but I can't guarantee that query would return the price in that case.

**Scenario 2 (with auxiliary class)**.

Needed steps:

1. Add new auxiliary class ShoppingItemsWithPrice (this class should not persist in DB, so it has no @Entity).

   `public class ShoppingItemsWithPrice {
       @Embedded
       public ShoppingItems shoppingItems;
       @Relation(parentColumn = "referenceId", entityColumn = "id")
       public ReferenceItems referenceItems;
   }`
2. And you DAO query:

   `@Query("select * from shoppingItems")
   LiveData<List<ShoppingItemsWithPrice>> getShoppingItemsWithPrice()`

As a result, query returns you object with all you have in both tables. You can optimise that (to get just one needed field) according to [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542)

Comment: In the first option, does it return a third table because of JOIN ?

In the second option, an object of ShoppingItemsWithPrice will just be use to be displayed, am I right? So when I want to edit a ShoppingItem alone it will also edit the ShoppingItemsWithPrice that correspond? Same if I edit the Unit Price (Core of the question). Thanks !

Comment: Not exactly. You have to distinguish "tables" (sql-tables) and "objects" (instances of classes). Room - is an abstraction on the top of Sqlite. With the query-annotated-thing Room invokes getting result from Sqlite and it fulfil mapping it to your objects (filed by field). So in both scenarios you have only two tables and in both scenarios you should put your price-value only in first table. But in first scenario Room is mapping query-result to instance of your existing class, and in second - to instance of new auxiliary class.

Comment: Is there a better option among those two ? What a company would do ?

Comment: First option is more like a hack in Room (but without Room you have to implement something like that). You still can choose it if you don't want to change your existing code too much. Second option is cleaner to my opinion if you use Room and official Google documentation on Room describes this one

Comment: I finally understood clearly and implemented it. What if I want to get the total value (sum of amount * unit_value). Before I had a simple request because the amount and unit price where in shopping item, but now they are in 2 different objects. Could you help me there?

Comment: For that case I guess Scenario 1 (I wrote about) fits better. You should add new field "sum" to your "ShoppingItems" and in your query calculate it as (if I understood you correctly) "shoppingsItems.amount * referenceItem.unitPrice as sum". After that you'll get your sum in your ShoppingItems object. Scenario 2 with @Relation wouldn't get you such possibility (at least I don't know how to do that) - or in this scenario you should calculate sum manually, that's not a fun

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I thought. I did option 1 and it works like a charm. I did not know if they were a better idea but this one works. I will try some more stuff though